# Extract MCQs from String file into Arraylist of individual Questions object

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have this docx file which I am parsing using apache POI
.The file have questions and multiple answers like following

**1.  Question1


A.  Right Answer

B.  Wrong Answer

C.  Wrong Answer

D.  Wrong Answer**

2. Question2
   A.  Right Answer
   B.  Wrong Answer
   C.  Wrong Answer
   D.  Wrong Answer

Now I want to extract all questions into an arraylist of Question objects. But I need a regex pattern to split the string from word file into individual questions.

Can anyone suggest a good regex pattern for this?

Comment: probably something like this `\d\. \w+\?` (must be converted to java). yet your question is very broad and i bet there are much better ways to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Question class like following

```
public class Question {

String question;
String rightAnswer;
ArrayList<String> wrongAnswers;
public Question() {
    super();
    wrongAnswers=new ArrayList();
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}



public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}



public void setRightAnswer(String rightAnswer) {
    this.rightAnswer=rightAnswer;
}

public void addWrongAnswer(String wrongAnswer) {
    wrongAnswers.add(wrongAnswer);
    Collections.shuffle(wrongAnswers);
}

public String getRightAnswer() {
    return rightAnswer;
}

public String getRandomWrongAnswer() {
    Random random=new Random();
    int index=random.nextInt(3);
    return wrongAnswers.get(index);
}

public ArrayList<String> getWrongAnswers(){
    return wrongAnswers;
}


}
```

In your main method do the following

```
String regex = "[0-9\\(\\)]+\\.\\s(.*?)[0-9\\(\\)]+\\.\\s";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(wholeFileAsString);
    ArrayList<String> allQuestions = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        allQuestions.add(m.group(1));
    }
    System.out.println("Total Questions : "+allQuestions.size());
    for (String QuestionString : allQuestions) {
        String regex2 = "\\s[a-zA-Z]\\.\\s";
        String splits[] = QuestionString.split(regex2);
        String questionSt = splits[0];
        String rightAnswer = splits[1];
        String wrongAnswer1 = splits[2];
        String wrongAnswer2 = splits[3];
        String wrongAnswer3 = splits[4];
        Question question=new Question();
        question.setQuestion(questionSt);
        question.setRightAnswer(rightAnswer);
        question.addWrongAnswer(wrongAnswer1);
        question.addWrongAnswer(wrongAnswer2);
        question.addWrongAnswer(wrongAnswer3);
        System.out.println(question.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Does not work. It only extracting some answers of questions that match this pattern.

Comment: Try replacing line break of wholeString with empty. wholeFileAsString.replace("\n", "");